# Post to facebook wall as a visitor trough API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook page for a project I am doing. I embedded the timeline stream in my external website, but now I want visitors of my website to be able to post to my wall. They need to be able to post as themselves, not the administrator of the page.

How should I do this ?

@EDIT: I searched the facebook developers page allready ofcourse, but didn't find the info I need.

Comment: I dont know the answer, but maybe this is a site where you can find it - http://facebooksdk.net/

Comment: have a look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691425/how-do-you-post-to-the-wall-on-a-facebook-page-not-profile

OR

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750786/facebook-php-api-post-to-wall-falls-under-recent-posts-by-others

Comment: @Hackbard aren't you posting as the app or as the admin of the page instead of the account of the vistor ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case

[Facebook PHP API post to wall falls under "Recent Posts by Others"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750786/facebook-php-api-post-to-wall-falls-under-recent-posts-by-others)

they posting to a FB Wall maybe u have to check if the access token u get from the users allow  a post to a page wall.